# Python Scraping: How to separate multiple attributes in one cell (td)?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

When scraping an HTML table, if a cell (td) in the table has multiple attributes (See HTML snippet for example) how can you separate the two and/or how could you select just one?

HTML snippet:

```
<td class="playerName md align-left pre in post" style="display: table-cell;"><span ...</span>
<a role="button" class="full-name">Dustin Johnson</a>
<a role="button" class="short-name">D.  Johnson</a></td>
```

Code I'm trying:

```
url = 'http://www.espn.com/golf/leaderboard?tournamentId=3742'

req = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text,'lxml')

table = soup.find(id='leaderboard-view')
headings = [th.get_text() for th in table.find('tr').find_all('th')]

dataset = []

for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    a = [td.get_text() for td in row.find_all('td')]
    dataset.append(a)
```

Any advice on how to either a) select just one of the names, or b) separate the cell in to two cells would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What are you expecting as the output?

Comment: I am trying to scrape the table from the website.  But I need the two name flavors in separate columns so that I can lookup scores by player name.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the full name and short name, you can try this:

```
for td in row.find_all('td'):
    full_name = td.find('a', {'class': 'full-name'}).text
    short_name = td.find('a', {'class': 'short-name'}).text
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use regex to match the tr

```
players = the_soup.findAll('tr',{'class':re.compile("player-overview")})
for p in players:
    name = p.find('a',{'class':'full-name'}).get_text()
```